# Archive dissapeared on dashboard

Tags: archives

Archive on main menus visible and all contents but going on dashboard to edit it’s disappeared from all pages. How to restore

Comment: As my crystal ball is on the blink you will need to add far more details. Right now I doubt I could even offer you a wild guess.